# How to get __zone_symbol__value in global variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

This is console log of html2pdf worker data, i am not able to store that __zone_symbol__value data in global variable.

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: "data:application/pdf;filename=generated.pdf;base64"

Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Worker
```

My code:

```
this.pdfString = any;
this.pdfString = html2pdf().from(element).set(options).toPdf().output('datauristring').then(res => {
  return res;
});

console.log(this.pdfString);
```

Comment: have you found the solution? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Not yet, i tried different way to tackle this issue.